# ftp directory in Python 3

Tags: python, ftp

I have the following code in Python 3.3:

```
ftpHost="myhost"
link=ftplib.FTP(ftpHost)
link.login(user="me",passwd="alsome")
t=link.nlst()
link.quit()
print(t)
```

The output I get is

```
['.','..','dir1','dir2']
```

In the Python 3 document, it is written that FTP.nlst has been "deprecated since version 3.3: use mlsd() instead". When I tried

```
ftpHost="myhost"
link=ftplib.FTP(ftpHost)
link.login(user="me",passwd="alsome")
t=link.mlsd()
link.quit()
print(t)
```

The output I get is

```
<generator object mlsd at 0x0000000002A0F120>
```

which is not the desired answer. I can't figure out where within t can I get the directory listing. How can I use mlsd to get the directory listing?

If I try @fourtheye 's suggestion and change to
    t=list(link.mlsd)

the error I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/xyz/python-test/python-test.py", line 17, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/xyz/python-test/python-test.py", line 12, in main
    t=list(link.mlsd())
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.3.2.1\python-3.3.2.amd64\lib\ftplib.py", line 556, in mlsd
    self.retrlines(cmd, lines.append)
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.3.2.1\python-3.3.2.amd64\lib\ftplib.py", line 446, in retrlines
    with self.transfercmd(cmd) as conn, \
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.3.2.1\python-3.3.2.amd64\lib\ftplib.py", line 386, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.3.2.1\python-3.3.2.amd64\lib\ftplib.py", line 352, in ntransfercmd
    resp = self.sendcmd(cmd)
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.3.2.1\python-3.3.2.amd64\lib\ftplib.py", line 259, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.3.2.1\python-3.3.2.amd64\lib\ftplib.py", line 233, in getresp
    raise error_perm(resp)
ftplib.error_perm: 500 MLSD not understood
```

Comment: I hope `alsome` is not your actual password.

Comment: @thefourtheye no it is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who runs the FTP host?  The `500 MLSD not understood` means they don't support the MLSD command.  That's a later extension to the FTP command set, so they're just out of date.  The specification is here:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3659

Unless and until they upgrade to a "modern" version of FTP, just continue to use `nlst()`.

Comment: thanks. the FTP site is run by vendor I have subscribed data to!

Comment: @uday, contact the vendor and ask them to please update their host software, specifically to support the MLSD command.  You can send them the link I gave you.  In the meantime, don't worry - `nlst()` appears to work fine, right?

Answer (score 3):

Generators dont keep entire results in the memory. The results will be generated when asked for one, with `next` function. In order to get the values as a list, use the `list` function with `link.mlsd()`, which will internally call `next` on the generator object.

Just change

```
t=link.mlsd()
```

to

```
t=list(link.mlsd())
```

Comment: @uday Please update the question with the error message as well.

Comment: @uday I suppose it has nothing to do with the generator part.